# onClick FloatingActionButton on fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

please. how to call fragment to activity using

```
 FloatingActionButton tambahpendor=(FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.floatingToko);
    tambahpendor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent sae = new Intent(getActivity(), ImputToko_Activity.class);
            startActivity(sae);

        }
    });
```

Comment: If your FloatingActionButton action button is in activity then do getActivity(). so : getActivity().findViewById(R.id.floatingToko);

Comment: Your Question is not clear, Please specify what exactly you want to archive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do it like this :

```
FloatingActionButton tambahpendor=(FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.floatingToko);
tambahpendor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, new FragmentName());
    transaction.commit();
}
});
```

where `container is the id of the main element in your activities xml file`.

Comment: if it helped you then please upvote and if it solved your problem then mark it as answer so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
FloatingActionButton tambahpendor=(FloatingActionButton)view.findViewById(R.id.floatingToko);
tambahpendor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       getImputTokoActivity();

    }
});

getImputTokoActivity()  {
        Intent sae = new Intent(getActivity(), ImputToko_Activity.class);
        startActivity(sae);
}
```

Hope so it helps, Because sometimes java8 features are not known.